# Ошибка при создании бота на телеграм (Python telebot)

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["command"]) # В commands может быть несколько разных команд
def answer(message):
    command = message.split(maxsplit=1)[1] # В переменной будет всё,что идёт после /comman
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
command = message.split(maxsplit=1)[1] AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Найдите ошибку пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сперва получить текст из объекта message. Попробуйте так:

```
command = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить текст, надо обратиться к `message.text`
Таким образом, ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=["command"])
def answer(message):
    command = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
```